# Converting code using nlme::lme to lme4::lmer

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models, nlme

I'm following the R code ([here](https://content.sph.harvard.edu/fitzmaur/ala2e/R_sect_19_5.html)) in Applied Longitudinal Analysis by Fitzmaurice, Laird and Ware to conduct a penalized spline regression analysis using `nlme::lme`. My actual application will have many more random coefficients, so I plan to use `lme4::lmer`. I'm having trouble translating the random spline terms `bf1-bf22` in the linked code to one that is compatible in `lmer`. If I understand the `lme` implementation, random intercepts are specified for the piecewise splines (variables with prefix `bf`). I (naively) tried adding `s(time,k=22,bs='re')` in the RHS of the formula in `lmer` (code below shows `gamm4`, which uses `lme4` functions), but that does not seem to work.

The data can be downloaded from [here](https://content.sph.harvard.edu/fitzmaur/ala2e/progesterone.dta) and the code is reproduced below.

```
library(foreign)

ds <- read.dta("progesterone.dta") #Wherever the file is stored)
attach(ds)

bf1 <- (time+7)*I(time > -7)
bf2 <- (time+6)*I(time > -6)
bf3 <- (time+5)*I(time > -5)
bf4 <- (time+4)*I(time > -4)
bf5 <- (time+3)*I(time > -3)
bf6 <- (time+2)*I(time > -2)
bf7 <- (time+1)*I(time > -1)
bf8 <- (time)*I(time > 0)
bf9 <- (time-1)*I(time > 1)
bf10 <- (time-2)*I(time > 2)
bf11 <- (time-3)*I(time > 3)
bf12 <- (time-4)*I(time > 4)
bf13 <- (time-5)*I(time > 5)
bf14 <- (time-6)*I(time > 6)
bf15 <- (time-7)*I(time > 7)
bf16 <- (time-8)*I(time > 8)
bf17 <- (time-9)*I(time > 9)
bf18 <- (time-10)*I(time > 10)
bf19 <- (time-11)*I(time > 11)
bf20 <- (time-12)*I(time > 12)
bf21 <- (time-13)*I(time > 13)
bf22 <- (time-14)*I(time > 14)


Const <- factor(rep(1,length(logp)))

group.time <- group*time
group.bf15 <- group*bf15
require(nlme)
model_lme <- lme(logp ~ time + group + group.time + group.bf15, 
              random=list(Const=pdIdent(~-1 + bf1 + bf2 + bf3 + bf4 + bf5 + bf6 + 
                                        bf7 + bf8 + bf9 + bf10 + bf11 + bf12 + bf13 + bf14 + bf15 + bf16 + 
                                        bf17 + bf18 + bf19 + bf20 + bf21 + bf22), 
                          id=pdSymm(~time)))


require(gamm4)
require(mgcv)
model_lmer <- gamm4(logp ~ time + group + group.time + group.bf15 +
                   s(time,k=22,bs="re") + s(time,id,k=22,bs="re"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### load packages

```r
library(foreign)
library(nlme)
library(gamm4)
library(mgcv)
library(ggplot2); theme_set(theme_bw())
library(cowplot)
```

### process data

I streamlined the process of creating the individual linear spline basis functions ... (`attach()` is almost never a good idea ...)

```r
ds <- read.dta("progesterone.dta") #Wherever the file is stored)
dss <- within(ds, {
    for (i in (-7):14) {
        assign(paste0("bf",i+8), (time+i)*as.numeric(time > i))
    }
})
matplot(dss[dss$id==1,5:26], type ="l")
dss$Const <- factor(rep(1,nrow(dss)))
```

### fit lme model with linear splines

Again, streamlining (using `reformulate` rather than writing out all of the `bf1 + bf2 + ...` terms; using `time*group` rather than constructing all the dummies/interactions by hand).

```r
model_lme <- lme(logp ~ time*group + I(group*bf15), 
                 random=list(Const=pdIdent(
                                 reformulate(c("-1",
                                               paste0("bf",1:22)))),
                             id=pdSymm(~time)),
                 data = dss)
```

### gamm4 version

```r
ds$bf15 <- dss$bf15
model_gamm4 <- gamm4(logp ~time*group + I(group*bf15) +
                         s(time, bs = "cs"),
                     ## need parentheses!
                     random = ~(time|id),
                     data = ds)
```

A few things to note here: (1) the collection of spline terms is represented by `s(time, bs = "cs")` (where "cs" stands for "cubic spline": see `?smooth.construct.cs.smooth.spec` [substitute for 'cs' to see the help for other choices of smooths]); (2) the other RE term in the original model is a random-slopes term with respect to time (`id = pdSymm(~time)`), which is represented here as a separate `random = (time|id)`; this component is handled on the `lmer`-fitting side, not by constructing an `mgcv` basis for it.

### compare predictions

```r
dss2 <- data.frame(ds, pred1 = predict(model_lme), pred2 = predict(model_gamm4$mer))
gg0 <- ggplot(dss, aes(time, logp, colour = factor(group))) + geom_point()
plot_grid(gg0 + geom_line(data=dss2, aes(group=id, y = pred1)) + 
                 labs(title = "lme (linear)"),
   gg0 + geom_line(data=dss2, aes(group=id, y = pred2)) + 
                 labs(title = "gamm4 (cubic)"))
```

[image]

I also tried this in `mgcv`:

```r
model_gam <- gam(logp ~time*group + I(group*bf15) +
                     s(time, bs = "cs") + s(id, time, bs = "re") +
                     s(id, bs = "re"),
                 data = dss, method = "REML")
```

The only obvious difference is that the slope and intercept REs are specified independently rather than being correlated, but the predicted values are quite different; I don't know if that's something about the model fit, or something different about how the random effects are treated during prediction ...

Comment: Thanks! If I wanted to use `lmer` instead of `gamm4` (e.g. manually specify splines like in the text) how would the syntax look?

Comment: It's actually a little tricky in `lme4` at present, as `lme4` doesn't offer a "homogeneous diagonal variance" customization option as `lme` does. Could be hacked. Might be easier in `glmmTMB`, but would be not-entirely trivial in any case. Probably a separate question, and you might need to have a pretty good reason (I know `gamm4` is clunky; I have some code to make working with it a *little* bit less painful here: https://github.com/bbolker/mmd_utils/blob/master/gamm4_utils.R )

Comment: Wanted to clarify a term in the `gamm4` model - is the smoothing done by `s(time,bs="cs")` doing the same thing as the random effects for the sum of `bf` terms in the `Const=pdIdent(...)` call in `lme`?

Comment: Approximately - although the penalty term is different ("cs" sets things up so that the penalty term is proportional to the integrated second derivative of the curve, rather than to the sum of squared magnitudes of the individual components ...)